# How to use netty to open the new session ticket of TLSv1.3?

Tags: netty

## My chakan netty4.1.97 source code is open by default, but there is still no new session ticket package.

I see netty source code need use PSK_DHE-KE but i don't know how to realize，this is right?
i can use openssl command to appear new session Ticket, but you can't use netty

who can help me This problem has been bothering me for a long time